# Disable edit using querymodechange and sort by form field status

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I have created a global variable name parameter. I create this parameter to disable edit mode. I have a status field differentiate by "Active", "Inactive", and "Draft".

```
Sub Querymodechange(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)
    Dim session As New NotesSession     
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc  As NotesDocument
    Dim view As NotesView
    Continue = False

    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set view = db.GetView("(Parameter)")    

    Set doc = view.GetDocumentByKey("UnderInspection", True)
    If doc Is Nothing Then
        Msgbox "Parameter not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If doc.PValue(0)="1" Then
        Msgbox "Under Inspection! "
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Continue = True
End Sub
```

As an above code, I will set parameter for form using Querymodechange. If its true, it will continue to false, else it continue to true.

My question is, how can I set querymodechange for status field name "Active" and "Inactive"? E.g when the status of the document is "Active" or "Inactive", it will use this querymodechange as it will disable edit mode. But for "Draft" status, you can edit. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by why you're doing it this way.  There's a field in the document that says whether you can edit that document, right?  And that field places the document in a view.  You then search the view to find out of the document has that field and then enable/disable edit mode accordingly.  Do I have that right?  The better way is just to use hide-when fields.  You have the edit field, say "FirstName" and then either a Computed for Display or Computed Text whose formula is FirstName.  Then hide the edit field if you don't want them to edit and hide the Display field when you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If source.Document.GetItemValue("Status")(0)<>"Draft" Then
     ...
     Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: PS you also have to do a similar check in the QueryOpen event. It is possible to open a document directly in Edit mode.

Comment: Okay I success get the querymodechange work well. Can I ask, how to revert back to enable Active status can edit after Draft saved. Lets say I have save Draft, then Active can be edit back.

Comment: Isn't that conflicting with your state conditions? What if someone already made a new Draft copy of your Active document, and you want to revert? There would be 2 Draft documents. Is that permitted? And why revert, if you can simply create a new Draft?